# Setting caps lock key to CTRL but still function as caps lock if I press for long enough

Tags: keyboard, caps-lock

I just started out using `tmux`, so I figured I would set my <kbd>Caps lock</kbd> key equal to the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key.

Though sometimes I do need the <kbd>Caps lock</kbd> key. I don't care if it requires playing with the Terminal or system files, I'm not afraid of that. However it would be nice if I could just run Terminal commands so that I can put it in a script. Also, if possible, it would be nice if it doesn't require extra software, although if it's necessary then there's no problem.

How can I make it so that it's normally a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, but if I press it for say 5 seconds it triggers a normal <kbd>Caps lock</kbd>. I was wondering, how can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using KeyRemap4MacBook, you could add this to [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en):

`<autogen>--HoldingKeyToKey-- KeyCode::CONTROL_L, KeyCode::CONTROL_L, KeyCode::VK_NONE, KeyCode::CAPSLOCK, Option::NOREPEAT</autogen>`

The threshold for holding a key is 0.2 s by default, but it can be changed in the second tab.

This would change fn+caps lock (control) to caps lock:

`<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::CONTROL_L, ModifierFlag::FN, KeyCode::CAPSLOCK</autogen>`

Comment: That would work. However this old Mac keyboard doesn't have an fn key (it's kind of old). How could I change that to option+capslock?

Comment: Also, I suppose this requires KR3MB? Yes? If so, is there a way not to use KR4MB?

Comment: Just change `ModifierFlag::FN` to `ModifierFlag::OPTION`. I don't know any other way to do it.